# Big difference between waking and resting heart rate

Tags: cardiology, heart-rate

I recently got an Apple Watch and am using the HeartWatch app. I'm concerned because my sedentary heart rate is pretty high - it's about 85 bpm with frequent spikes to 100, but my waking heart rate is much lower at 65 bpm. I exercise about 5 days per week and am pretty healthy.

Is there a resource of statistics on averages among the population for waking vs resting vs sleeping heart rates?

Comment: Apple Watches and pulse measurements in general are inaccurate. The spikes suggest that there might be a measurement error. Sometimes, you pulse oximeter tells you you have a pulse of 250 bpm, can't be, neither can sudden spikes. What is a sedentary heart rate and a waking heart rate? I only know resting heart rate as a term.

Comment: I edited your post to delete your questions (and tags) about social anxiety because those were asking for medical advice. We don't know and won't attempt to tell you why your heart rate is higher in social situations.